# How would I allow admins on my webpage to directly change the text displayed on that page without accessing the backend?

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

So I am building a website which allows users to login and certain users have admin privileges.  One of the requests from an admin was to be able to have the ability to change text on the homepage.  How would I go about allowing them to permanently change the html on the page, preferably from the webpage itself?  I've seen the contenteditable='true' tag, but I'm not sure how I would get that to stick.

```
   <?php
   $access = "A";
   ?>
   <p id='body'>
       This is the homepage of placeholdername.com.  If you are unhappy 
       with this text, an admin will edit it.
   </p>
```

Some tips on where to start would be great.

EDIT: I guess this wasn't a great place to ask this question based on the downvotes but I think I got the answers I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: I think you are talking about a CMS (Content Management System) Rather too broad for a question on SO

Comment: Thanks, I know its a broad question but I wasn't sure where to ask it. I don't expect anyone to come in here with any specific code or anything, I was just hoping for some tips.

Comment: there are a few (PHP) functions to write to file, if that's what the question's about; *seems to be*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really sounds like you are looking for a CMS (content management system). Have a look at Joomla or Wordpress. Just google those two big ones for a start and go for alternatives if they do not give you what you want.

Both are highly customizable and give you all kinds of functionality as a present out of the box. You can use premade themes for the frontend, have a quite sophisticated user management with highly customizable read/write permissions (sounds like what you are looking for), your admins and users do not need to understand a bit of webdevel to do the coolest things and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [CK Editor](http://ckeditor.com/). You can add it to any web page.  It is a great WYSIWYG editor that works live on the page and can be restricted to specific areas of the page and specific users.  And it is FREE!

Answer (score 0):

Create a button that will be visible only if the logged in user is admin and then try something like this with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn_id").click(function(){

        $(".#body").css("display", "none");
        $('<textarea rows="15" name="body" class="form-control" value="'$(".#body").val'"></textarea>').appendTo("#body");
    $("#btn").html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i> Save');
    });
 });
```